# Try catch not working in child thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread that runs a `while-true` loop:

```
from threading import Thread, Event

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, thread_id, name, counter, thread_func):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.thread_id = thread_id
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
        self.thread_func = thread_func
        self._stop_event = Event()

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                self.thread_func()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'keyboard interrupt'
            self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        """
        stops the thread
        """
        self._stop_event.is_set()
```

The goal is to catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` event and stop the thread. However, I am unable to execute the `except` block with an interrupt. When I place this try/catch on the main thread, however, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard interrupt is not received by the child threads. You can catch the exception in main thread and execute a callback, for example, killing children thread.
Here's a sample code exemplifying:

```
import threading
if __main__ == "__name__":
    t1 = threading.Thread()
    t2 = threading.Thread()
    try:
       t1.start()
       t2.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
       t1.join()
       t2.join()
```

Comment: oops! Suppose to be  `join` :)